# How do I apply this function to a whole geopandas data frame and return a new dataframe with all matches?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I need to apply the following function to all points in a `GeoDataFrame`

```
def radius(gpd_df, cpt, radius=0.01):

    sindex = gpd_df.sindex
    bbox = (cpt.geometry.x-radius, 
            cpt.geometry.y-radius, 
            cpt.geometry.x+radius, 
            cpt.geometry.y+radius)

    good = []
    for n in sindex.intersection(bbox):
        dist = cpt.geometry.distance(gpd_df['geometry'][n])
        if dist<radius:
            good.append((cpt[0],dist,n))

    good.sort() 

    return [x for x in good]
```

but notice it may return more than one match per input point, so I should create a new `DataFrame`.

I'm testing the function with `test = radius(df.iloc[0], aa, 0.011)` but I've a feeling that although that gives me the correct responses, it's not generalizable (and not even sure it's right).

Comment: Try using new_df = df.pipe(radius, cpt)

Comment: @Peter: thanks, but what's `cpt` in the call?

Comment: I don't know? That depends on what cpt would be in your model. Your function radius() needs ctp as an input

Comment: @Peter: I've edited the question a bit. `cpt` should be some element of a pandas `Series`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the problem, though I'd be interested in making it prettier or more pythonic.

So, I have a `GeoDataFrame` called `gpd` which has info and `shapely.Point`s. The function ended up like (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752555/50305), with thanks):

```
def radius2(gpd_df, cpt, radius):
    sindex = gpd_df.sindex

    bbox = (cpt[1].x-radius, 
            cpt[1].y-radius, 
            cpt[1].x+radius, 
            cpt[1].y+radius)

    good = []
    for n in sindex.intersection(bbox):
        dist = cpt[1].distance(gpd_df['geometry'][n])
        if dist<radius:
            good.append((cpt[0],dist,n))

    good.sort() 

    return good
```

Now I call it like

```
results = [radius2(aa, x, 0.01) for x in gt.values]
```

which gives me a list of lists of tuples, which in turn I just

```
def functools_reduce_iconcat(a):
    return functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, a, [])

red = functools_reduce_iconcat(results)
df = pd.DataFrame(red)
```

I know it's not pretty, but for now it will have to do.